# Can I account for start-up costs that occur before incorporation?

Tags: accounting, start-up

I'm starting an LLC with a couple of partners. But before we incorporate we need to finalize a partnership agreement.

I would like to initiate a few time-sensitive things such as a patent search before incorporation is complete. These lawyer services will come out of my pocket.

Can I include this in our financials as **capital investment** / **start-up costs** once incorporation is finalized?

**Can I account for start-up costs that occur before incorporation?**

Comment: OnStartups would be a better suited place for such a question, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. You should talk to your tax advisor re the specific expenditures that can be accounted as startup-costs (legal fees are a good candidate, for example). If they add up to significant amounts (>$5K), you'll have to capitalize them over a certain period of time, and deduct from your business' income.

This is not a tax advice.:-)